# How to expand the hitTest area of a UIButton without extruding it's background image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I have set the `UIButton`'s background image and put a title on it(I used `setBackgroundImage` method not `setImage`). Now I want to expand the hitTest area of a `UIButton` without extrude it's background image.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could extend UIButton and override UIView's hitTest method:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    int expandMargin = 20;
    CGRect extendedFrame = CGRectMake(0 - expandMargin , 0 - expandMargin , self.bounds.size.width + (expandMargin * 2) , self.bounds.size.height + (expandMargin * 2));
    return (CGRectContainsPoint(extendedFrame , point) == 1) ? self : nil;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. The `point` is in local coordinate system and using `frame` instead `bounds` will cause problems if `view`'s `origin` does not equal `CGPointZero`.

Comment: CGRectInset would be nicer than insane CGRectMake

Answer (score 7):

A cleaner way to do this is to override pointInside.

Here's a Swift version:

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let expandedBounds = CGRectInset(self.bounds, -15, -15)
    return CGRectContainsPoint(expandedBounds, point)
}
```

Comment: Don't forget a check if your view is visible and has a window, else you might get fun results...

Comment: @steipete wish your comment had been posted earlier ... the results were not so fun!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a corrected version of the accepted answer. We're using `bounds` instead of `frame` and `CGRectInset` instead of `CGRectMake`. Cleaner and more reliable.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return CGRectContainsPoint([self expandedBounds], point) ? self : nil;
}

- (CGRect)expandedBounds {
    return CGRectInset(self.bounds, -20, -20);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This version lets you define a minimum hit size for all UIButtons. Crucially, it also handles the case when UIButtons are hidden, which many answers neglect.

```
extension UIButton {
    public override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        // Ignore if button hidden
        if self.hidden {
            return nil
        }

        // If here, button visible so expand hit area
        let hitSize = CGFloat(56.0)
        let buttonSize = self.frame.size
        let widthToAdd = (hitSize - buttonSize.width > 0) ? hitSize - buttonSize.width : 0
        let heightToAdd = (hitSize - buttonSize.height > 0) ? hitSize - buttonSize.height : 0
        let largerFrame = CGRect(x: 0-(widthToAdd/2), y: 0-(heightToAdd/2), width: buttonSize.width+widthToAdd, height: buttonSize.height+heightToAdd)
        return (CGRectContainsPoint(largerFrame, point)) ? self : nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a [library](https://github.com/kgaidis/KGHitTestingViews) for this very purpose.

You can choose to use a category, **no subclassing required**:

```
@interface UIView (KGHitTesting)
- (void)setMinimumHitTestWidth:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height;
@end
```

Or you can subclass your UIView or UIButton and set the `minimumHitTestWidth` and/or `minimumHitTestHeight`. Your button hit-test area will then be represented by these 2 values.

Just like other solutions, it uses the `- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method. The method is called when iOS performs hit-testing. [This](http://smnh.me/hit-testing-in-ios/) blog post has a good description on how iOS hit-testing works.

https://github.com/kgaidis/KGHitTestingViews

```
@interface KGHitTestingButton : UIButton <KGHitTesting>

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat minimumHitTestHeight; 
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat minimumHitTestWidth;

@end
```

You can also just subclass and use the Interface Builder without writing any code:
[image]