# How to increase tap area of back button in navigation bar without using contentEdgeInsets?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am adding to my navigation bar a back button using the following code. The back item is added to the left side. I need to increase the tap area on the left and right side of the back button so it is tappable. I used `contentEdgeInsets` property of the back button but it moves the button to the right or left depending on the number inset i use. Is it possible to increase the tap area from the left side of the button and the right side of the button without moving the button?

```
 CGSize size = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
 UIImage *image = [self make];
 UIButton *back = [self.class buttonForBarItemByImage:image size:size];
 back.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0, 0);
 UIBarButtonItem *backArrow = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:back];
[back addTarget:backArrow action:@selector(backArrow_onClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

+ (UIButton *) buttonForBarItemByImage:(UIImage *)image size:(CGSize)size {
    UIButton *back = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [back setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    CGSize buttonSize = size;
    back.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height);
    return back;
}

+ (UIImage *) make {
    
    /// calculate label (image) and canvas size
    
    CGSize imageSize;
    CGSize canvasSize;
    if (self.paddingExpandsSize) {
        imageSize = self.size;
        canvasSize = CGSizeMake(self.size.width + self.padding.left + self.padding.right,
                                self.size.height + self.padding.top + self.padding.bottom);
    } else {
        canvasSize = self.size;
        imageSize = CGSizeMake(self.size.width - self.padding.left - self.padding.right,
                                      self.size.height - self.padding.top - self.padding.bottom);
    }
    
    /// create and setup canvas
    
    UIView * canvas = [UIView new];
    canvas.size = canvasSize;
    
    canvas.layer.borderWidth = self.borderWidth;
    canvas.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadius;
    canvas.layer.borderColor = self.borderColor.CGColor;
    
    /// crate and setup label (image)
    
    UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
    
    CGFloat fontSize = MIN(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    
    CGFloat corrImageWidth = imageSize.width + 2 * self.strokePadding;
    CGFloat corrImageHeight = imageSize.height + 2 * self.strokePadding;
    
    imageSize = CGSizeMake(corrImageWidth, corrImageHeight);
    
    label.size = imageSize;
        
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.fontName size:fontSize];
    label.font = font;
    
    NSMutableDictionary *imageAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    imageAttributes[NSFontAttributeName] = font;
    imageAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = self.color;
    imageAttributes[NSStrokeColorAttributeName] = self.strokeColor;
    imageAttributes[NSStrokeWidthAttributeName] = self.strokeWidth;
    imageAttributes[NSShadowAttributeName] = self.strokeShadow;
    
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    
    imageAttributes[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName] = paragraphStyle;
    
    NSMutableAttributedString *image = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.symbol
                                                                              attributes:imageAttributes];

    label.attributedText = image;
    label.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    
    /// place label (image) on canvas
    
    [canvas addSubview:label];
    label.origin = CGPointMake(self.padding.left - self.strokePadding, self.padding.top - self.strokePadding);
    
    /// generate resulting image
    
    return [canvas toImage];
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could subclass "back" `UIButton` and [override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12297806/1136218) the `hitTest` function?

Comment: you mean create a category of the UIButton class and use hittest function?

Comment: I mean [subclass](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/subclassing/) to override the function of the parent class. But whatever works better for you.